# How to test Android app on an Android phone and get the error logs?

Tags: android, testing, logcat

I am newbie to Android. I have been testing my apps on the emulator till date. 
I want to do the following:
1. I have a Android phone and I wish to test my app on this phone. 
2. I also want to know how to get the error logs while testing on the phone.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In Your device set the Debugger Mode Enabled in Setting,,,Connect your device to System,,Run your application, and the Log will be displayed on LogCat,,you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Any additional USB drivers or Adb drivers are needed for this?

Comment: No system will install them itself..If Internet is connected, system will install latest updated drivers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run you android application directly from IDE, keeping 'Debug Mode' on within 'Developer Options' in 'Settings', and thus can trace logcat.

You may also need to install 'ADB Drivers' for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The phone has have a developer option and there select usb debbuging. And in you android code use Log.e(TAG,"error:" e.getMessage(),e); <- e is an Exception or for just normal debbuging use Log.d or Log.v Log.i